# Django annotate(Count) multiple times on same field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to use `annotate` to add a count on a field in a queryset, and return the result based on different filters. In the example below, the model is `User` with a manytomany relation to `Article`. I would like to get a count on the User Articles for different values of the Article field `difficulty`:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(article__status='published')\
        .annotate(Count('article', distinct=True))
      .filter(article__difficulty='easy')\
        .annotate(Count('article', distinct=True))\
      .filter(article__difficulty='medium')\
        .annotate(Count('article', distinct=True))\
      .filter(article__difficulty='hard')\
        .annotate(Count('article', distinct=True))
```

This result returns only `article__count`, with the value for difficulty=hard.

Is there a way to get values for all four values in the same queryset?

Comment: you mean you want queryset to be sth like [4,2,5,9] in a single query ? (numbers of count of difficulties)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
(queryset.filter(article__status='published')
         .values('article__difficulty')
         .annotate(Count('article__difficulty')))
```